# Android 5.1 APP on 5.0 device?

Tags: android

I've just programmed a simple App for an Android 5.1 device but i was thinking if it is possible to also run it in Android 5.0.
As i know i Need to Change the gradle Settings but i am not sure what exactly:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.apps.mainUser.firstApp"
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Is it enough to Change the minSdkVersion to 21? And is it even possible to run a API 23 (Android 5.1) programmed App on a Android 5.0 device with those settings? Is there any way to "test" the app without any real device?

Comment: Make emulator of Android 21 api level (or Android 5).

Comment: API 23 == Marshmallow

Answer (score 1):

Yes just make `minSdkVersion` into  `21` and try to run it to emulator whose  Android api level is 21

Answer (score 1):

Yes you must change minSdk.I recommend to change  minSdkVersion 9 and targetSdkVersion 24

Comment: thanks for the reply. why exactly those sdk Versions?

Comment: you shall change `compileSdkVersion 24` if you set `targetSdkVersion 24`

Comment: The Android SDK (software development kit) is a set of development tools used to develop applications for Android platform. The Android SDK includes the following:
Required libraries
Debugger
An emulator
Relevant documentation for the Android application program interfaces (APIs)
Sample source code
Tutorials for the Android OS